# KIO Trash drive specific trash folder

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma, recycle-bin

I'm using KIO to implement trash functionality. The problem is that the files are all put into a single trash that's on a local drive. The problem with this approach is that deleting files on network drives takes too much time due to network delays. I want to have a trash folder for every mount point, e.g. /mnt/parition1/.Trash/uid/..., /mnt/parition2/.Trash/uid/... etc. I have been looking through the KIO docs and source code, and I can find a TrashImpl.cpp where it seems that multiple mount points are supported. But then looking at the KIO::trash function, there is absolutely no way to set this up.

So my question is, how can I make KIO::trash work such that it will trash on the partition instead to avoid costly network operations.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `KIO::move` with the destination set to `trash:/`, at least that is the way [`kioclient`](https://github.com/KDE/kde-cli-tools/blob/73c7c8f093045c8306bb67921394ded86d1bee4c/kioclient/kioclient.cpp#L267-L279) implements the move to trash functionality. This should use the drive/partition specific trash since it follows the [FreeDesktop.org trash specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html)